# Role based authorization and user access levels on MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, user-roles, access-levels

For a system I'm developing, I am using SimpleMembershipProvider and SimpleRoleProvider.

But according to a new requirement I feel like I can't use these anymore to authorize users on their roles and levels of access.

Currently, in the system, there are various types of Roles.

- Super Admin
- Admin
- Customer Care
- Support

These are stored in the "webpages_Roles" table and the Super Admin should be able to add new roles if necessary and assign access levels to users. So it means, if the "Super Admin" later wanted to change this role name as "Global Admin" the system should work fine. But right now, when this happens, everything breaks. Is there any better way to implement this scenario?

The other problem I am having is,

- "Super Admin" can add any user to the system in any role
- "Admin" can't view/create/update "Super Admin" accounts
- "Admin" can create/view/update "Admin" or any other role
- Other user roles can't view "Admin" or "Super Admin"

What would be a better way to design and implement these?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there anyone who can give me a suggestion? I thought this might be a common problem but no one answered yet.